# AWS Lambda function not scaling - why and what are the options?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a `python` `aws-lambda` function that takes in an image (geospatial raster) on S3, computes a subset and dumps it to another bucket on S3. The function only runs on demand, there's no schedule.

So basically it has 3 arguments:

- source
- destination
- subset window

Is as trying to invoke the function from my local PC in a loop, going over 1000+ sources:

```py
#...

# create lambda client from botocore session

lambda_client = session.create_client("lambda")

for file in input_files:

    # create payload body with source, destination, window
    # ... 

      response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName="foobar",
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload=json.dumps(payload)
    )

    assert response['ResponseMetadata']["HTTPStatusCode"] == 202
```

The function is set to have a maximum memory of `1024MB` and a timeout of `15s`, which seems to be just fine.

When I run the invocations, they take quite some time (which is fine) but for some reason, I don't get many concurrent invocations. I haven't set any limits, nor do I see any reason why it would get throttled.

I can see in the metrics dashboard, that I don't get more than 8 concurrent executions:

[image]

**A couple of Qs:**

- How can I run this function with a higher concurrency?
- Is there a better way to implement this kind of function?

**Notes:**

- I could easily dockerize the function, so porting to another service wouldn't be a big issue.
- I don't want to have an S3 trigger
- I didn't try adding an SQS queue as trigger
- I don't necessarily want to move to AWS batch, as I'm not familiar with it (yet) and don't want to spend the time now on reading up on it and get it running

Comment: Your function, on avg, takes 0.5 seconds to run. So they just probably complete before you can boost your concurrency. Basically your loop can make 8 `invoke` requests within 0.5 seconds, so you see only concurrency of 8.

Comment: Interesting, so you'd recommend either submitting batches of files for each invocation, or installing an SQS that handles it for me?

Comment: Do you *need* a higher concurrency if the data is being processed fast enough…?

Comment: @deceze as you can see in the dashboard it already took 30mins+. It doesn't have to be done instantaneously, especially when it starts incurring a higher cost (which I understand is not the case). But it shouldn't be an overnight job. So to answer your Q, I want more concurrency to process it faster

Comment: I think batch submitions would be useful. It would reduce the number of API calls to AWS.

Comment: @Marcin point taken, I knew batch would be a good alternative. But is it to the point that it's ridiculous to do this with lambda and I have to move to batch? I have to admit, I've not done the calculations

Comment: Your lambda execution times are very low, API calls take time. If you don't want to batch it, you can change your `for file in input_files` to submit `invoke` request in parallel, instead one-by-one as you do now. But batching would be my first choice to consider given the short execution times.

Comment: Another option is to setup a Kinesis stream, submit the work requests to the stream, then have an event setup so that each time a record is added to the Kinesis stream the Lambda function is triggered.  The other advantage of that is if the Lambda fails to process one of the images, and exits with an error, the record won't be marked "handled" and another Lambda will be triggered with the same record.  So if your have to worry about re-trying errors, you'll get that automatically as a bonus.

Comment: @cnamejj this is a very low-cost / low-importance application. Wouldn't adding a service like kinesis add considerable cost overhead? (disclaimer: I'm not very familiar with it)

Comment: Kinesis Streams (not Kinesis Firehose, just plain old Streams) are pretty inexpensive, but definitely lookup the costs before committing to that service.  The benefit over what you're doing is that submitting an entry to a stream is very quick and doesn't block until the Lamdba is triggered.

You do have to make sure your Lambda function exits cleanly (meaning no error code, no crash) after successfully handling and event otherwise it will get retried.

Comment: @Marcin your comments led to the correct solution. If you want, please post a solution I can accept. Thanks for your help! And thanks everyone else for their good suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The `Duration` metric shows that the **average execution time** of the lambda function is about 0.5 seconds. Since concurrency is about 8, this means that the `for` loop in the question makes about 8 requests within this time period.

Since the execution time is so short, a possible solution to improve the time efficiency is to **batch the requests**, so that multiple payloads are send to the function in a one API call. This not only reduces the number of API calls to AWS, but also extends the execution time of the function.

The alternative is to perform `invoke` API calls in **parallel**, rather then one-by-one as it is current done in the `for` loop.